Is the ordinate set of this step function a rectangle?
A rectangle is any set congruent (in the geometrical sense) to the set $\{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq h \wedge 0 \leq y \leq k\}$ for $h,k \geq 0$.
Let $s$ be a step function on the interval $[a,b]$ such that $s$ is constant on the open interval $(a, b)$,
$$\forall x\in (a, b): s(x)=c$$
And let $Q$ be the ordinate set of $s$,
$$Q=\{(x,y) : a \leq x \leq b \wedge 0 \leq y \leq s(x) \}$$
How can I show that $Q$ is also a rectangle (or is $Q$ not a rectangle)? Since $s(x_{k-1})$ and $s(x_k)$ might not equal $c$. So far, I've only proven the fact that the area of the ordinate set of a step function is equal to its integral. I want to show this because this fact is assumed in the book but not proven.
I've showed that $Q$ can also be written as,
$$
Q = \{(x,y) : (x = a \wedge 0 \leq y \leq s(a) 
\vee (a < x < b \wedge 0 \leq y \leq c) \vee (x = b \wedge 0 \leq y \leq s(b))\}
$$
but I'm not sure how to move on from here.
